# Better way of finding $P(A1 \cup A2 \cup A3)$

Tags: probability

A die is tossed thrice. Find the probability of getting an odd number at least once.

Recently did the above basic question. I simply evaluates $A1,A2$ and then $\cup$ them with $A3$. I was wondering if there was a simpler way to solve the problem however.

Comment: Just calculate the probability that all numbers are even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the complement of $A = \{\text{At least one odd in three rolls}\}$ is $\bar A = \{\text{No odds in 3 rolls}\}$. So 
$$P(A) = 1-P(\bar A)=1-\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^3 = \frac{7}{8}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Calculate $1$ minus the probability of the complementary event:

$$1-\left(\frac36\right)^3$$